# cannot share folder in `/media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>`

Tags: permissions, samba

`/media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>` has permission `(0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/ sambausr)   Gid: ( 1001/ sambausr)`

```
[for-widelink-test]
   path = /media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>
   read only = yes
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = no
   valid users = sambausr
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   unix extensions = no
```

If I try to access in windows10, it said `Windows cannot access \\ip\for-widelink-test\ You don not have permission to access ...`

But the apparmor setting seems correct too:

```
"/media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>"   rk,
"/media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>/**" rwkl,
```

If the path is point to a location in local disk it works. What else should I do to fix this?

**update**

I think I found the reason. To be able to access the , all the parent path need to be at least `r-x` to the sambausr. The `/media/<usr>` is not. To allow this need to use ACL to grant the sambausr `r-x` to the `/media/<usr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue for another option. Rather than mess about with the permissions of `/media/<username>` which was set as a security measure in Linux that one modify the samba share definition instead:

```
[for-widelink-test]
   path = /media/<username>/<somemount>/<somedir>
   read only = yes
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = no
   valid users = sambausr
   force user = <username> 
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   unix extensions = no
```

"valid users" will restrict who gets access to the share but once accepted that user will be converted to `<username>` by "force user" - at least for that share.

Comment: this is a far better way to do this. Thanks!